# I need to plot multiple y variables along a time series data frame within the same scatter plot

Tags: python, time-series

I have a time series dataframe in this format:

datestr |   Pressure  |  Temperture  |   y
09-22-2016 | 22  |44| 0
09-23-2016 | 2  |40| 0
09-24-2016 | 27  |52| 1
09-25-2016 | 33  |45| 0

The index is the datestr (which i need to plot along the x axis). The Pressure and Temperature are integer which id like to plot in the same plot. The Y value is binary which also needs to be plotted on the same plot( I would like to plot it vertically or as a single point since there is only one or two data points where the y >0)

I have tried pandas and matplotlib

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide more details of your issue and show us where you got stacked.

But from your question, I guess you are trying to look for a plot like this?
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html